# Excel display value occurring in the range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the column letter, which is a value. Because it's conditional-based its position will change. I need to have the column name displayed in one cell.

Now I have M at M50
but I can also have N at N50, O at O50 etc down to the P column

I need this value displayed in one cell i.e. in the place where my formula is stored.

[image]

I used the following function:

```
  =LOOKUP(L50:P50) but it shows me that I put too few arguments.
```

Is there any way of displaying the shifting value between several columns in the row only in one cell?

Comment: You must specify other parameter of `LOOKUP()` function.  See this https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb

Comment: Yes, but in this case I would need at least 5 parameters. Moreover, all tutorials show the function within column-based action. I have a transposed situation like you see. Everything happens in one row.

Comment: Lookup can be horizontal, but you need to provide what you are looking for at least.  But you should also provide what to return.  That function requires 2 entries at least, with a third optional.  If you explain better what you have and what you are trying to return, with copiable test data, we can probably help.

Comment: Ok I've expanded my question, are you able to help me now?

Comment: Is `=L50:P50` what you want?

Comment: `=TOCOL(L50:P50,3)` maybe? I assumed there to be one value somewhere? Or even `=CONCAT(L50:P50)`.

Comment: So you are looking for the only value in a row of 5 cells that is not blank?

Comment: `=LOOKUP(1,1/(L50:P50<>""),L50:P50)`

Comment: @JvdV = the CONCAT function works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: It was a wild quess.

Comment: I think it might be good to explain the purpose. Are you using this for another calculation? Maybe that could be somplyfied.

Comment: Yes, Now i am applying it for the INDIRECT function

Answer (score 0):

Try

=TEXTJOIN("",, Select_Your_Expected_Result_Range)